# Ramda undefined when using compose

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm working through the "Mostly Adequate Guide" exercises for chapter five.  I've imported Ramda with

```
var R = require('ramda');
```

and have written the helper function:

```
var _average = function(xs) {
    return R.reduce(R.add, 0, xs) / xs.length;
};
```

which works fine used on its own like

```
_average(R.map(R.prop('dollar_value'), cars));
```

but when I compose it like so:

```
var averageDollarValue = R.compose(_average(), R.map(R.prop('dollar_value')));
```

I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
```

Can someone explain why this is occurring?

Comment: Are you sure that `R.map(R.prop('dollar_value'))(yourData)` is actually returning a list of numbers and not, say, `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parens in your composition mean you are calling the function _average in your composition. Try removing them, this worked for me. Here is the code snippet.

```
var averageDollarValue = R.compose(_average, R.map(R.prop('dollar_value')));
```

Comment: Yes!  I think I got a little too comfortable with Ramda's "curried by default" philosophy.  Thank you for your answer.